# Open JS menu on first click, on 2nd click go to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create a dropdown menu that when first click, shows the children elements, if you click on a child you go to the childs url and if you click the country name again the child menu collapses.

I've got it working to an extent on I can't get the children to link through to their respective links.

Im guessing its to do with my `e.preventDefault` ?

**JS**

```
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active'))     {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65 );
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4gz3e0s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

just add `javascript:void(0);` inside the href attribute of your languages.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);">English</a>`

And remove the preventDefault:

```
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active'))     {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65 );
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }

});
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4gz3e0s/4/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click event is being propagated up the ancestors as the items are nested under the click target (the `.sub-lang` element). The `e.preventdefault()` therefore stops *all link clicks* anywhere inside that element from performing their default behaviour.

You could just check that the target is the sub-link and conditionally return true or false to allow default behaviour:

```
return !$(e.target).parent().hasClass('active');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/k4gz3e0s/5/